# How to search for an exact match in Facebook Marketplace

Tags: facebook

I want to search Facebook Marketplace and only see listings that contain the search term.  This seems like it should be the default behavior, but it's not.  Currently if I search for "lego", my first 8 results include 5 listings without the word lego anywhere in the listing, and 3 that are actually lego.  The 5 other listings are only vaguely related to lego - they contain words like "toy" or "minecraft".